# Click on Menu Item on toolbar don't work with Navigationview

Tags: android, click, menuitem, navigationview, android-navigationview

I have a problem with an "onClick" event, with NavigationView and Menu item.
My  explanation : I have an activity, which is a child of my "root" activity.
In this, I have a menu item on the top_right in my toolbar, which can allow me to take a picture.
Also, I use a NavigationView, so I override it to return at my "root" activity when I click on it (With setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false), it shows me a "back" button).
Problem: When I click on my menu item which is the "camera" item, it has the same behaviour when I click on my NavigationView (Which is a "back" button), it returns on my "root" activity.
In my opinion, the problem comes to the "setDrawerIndicatorEnabled" function, but I didn't find any correct answer.

Any idea?

Thanks for our help !

Code for my menu item :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_mission_detail, menu);
}

@Override
protected void onChangeStarted(@NonNull ControllerChangeHandler changeHandler, @NonNull ControllerChangeType changeType) {
    setOptionsMenuHidden(!changeType.isEnter);

    if (changeType.isEnter) {
        setTitle();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_photo) {
        onCameraClicked();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Hello can you post your menu item code or the file code where you are using menu item

Comment: Hello, I update my post!

Comment: Does anyone have a solution?